# Twopage even-odd thrown after inserting pdf page with Roman page numbering

Tags: pdfpages, double-sided

I think I have trouble with a twopage document. My second page is a single page document. For my understanding, after that it should be an odd page with the page number on the right. After the PDF come some pages with roman page numbering containing table of contents etc. Put the first page of them (page 3) is having the page number on the left, not on the right. After these pages, page numbering is switched back to arabic an there the even-odd switching works as supposed. In my example code at the end of this post, this leads to pages 3 (with roman numbering) and page 4 (arabic numbering) having their page number on the left, which isn't supposed to happen. Something like `\cleardoublepage` or `\cleardoubleoddpage` doesn't fix that.

Anybody got any idea how that could be fixed?

```
\documentclass[titlepage,12pt,twoside,pagesize=auto,listof=totocnumbered,table,xcdraw]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,ilines]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\tocloftpagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\lipsum[1-4]\\
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{normalsize}
\today
\end{normalsize}
\end{center}
\newpage

\includepdf{test.pdf} % replace with any one page PDF document

\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\tocloftpagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\ohead{}
\ifoot{}
\cfoot{}
\ofoot{}


\tableofcontents
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead{\pagemark}
\chead{}
\ohead{\headmark}
\ifoot{}
\cfoot{}
\ofoot{}

\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\cleardoublepage` after the includepdf and after tableofcontents works fine for me.

Comment: Doesn't for me. The problem is the page with the table of contents, not the page afterwards. This only makes the problem worse since it would only move all odd pages to even pages after the roman numbered part

Comment: you put the page number in \ihead. That is the inner margin and so on the left on odd pages. If you want them in the outer margin use \ohead.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the tip. I expected it to be the other way round as I'm only using someone else's template and because it worked as I expected it to work in the arabic umbered part. So I'll have to check back before publishing which way things are supposed to be.